# Garmin-Watchface: How to show Heartrate?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

In a watchface I created which ConnectIQ (4.30) I can show the clocktime, but when I try to show the heartrate I get the error

> Details: Module 'Toybox.Sensor' not available to 'Watch Face'
>
> Stack: 
>     - onStart() at /Users/…/source/_garmin_projectAPP.mc:13 0x10000095 Permission Required

In the manifest I added all available permissions, I also imported the Sensor with

> using Toybox.Sensor

I am also not sure where exactly to enable the heartrate-sensor with e.g.

```
Sensor.setEnabledSensors([Sensor.SENSOR_HEARTRATE]);
Sensor.enableSensorEvents(method(:onSensor));
```

I tried in the `initialize()` and `onStart(state)` method, but still I get the error shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIQ apps of type "watch face" do not have access to sensors in that manner. Instead you need to use the methods available in the Activity and/or ActivityMonitor modules.

If the watch device is newer it will likely support calling this method, which returns an heart rate value that is updated every second:

```
Activity.getActivityInfo().currentHeartRate()
```

Otherwise, you can call this method and use the most recent value, which will be the heart rate within the last minute:

```
ActivityMonitor.getHeartRateHistory()
```

In both cases you will need to check for a null value, which will happen if the sensor is not available or the user is not wearing the watch.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: In case it helps anybody, currentHeartRate isn't a function call, should just be `Activity.getActivityInfo().currentHeartRate`.  (Though that just gets me null, so I may still have it wrong.)

Comment: Activity.getActivityInfo().currentHeartRate returns correct value while activity is started.
While using simulator - yes, it returns null value - i found it while using both simulator and uploading and testing on current device.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me.  I had to do this, using currentHeartRate as a property, not a function method.

```
    var heartRate = null;
    var activity = Activity.getActivityInfo();
    if (activity != null) {
        heartRate = activity.currentHeartRate;
    }
```

I was able to also test this in the simulator using Simulation->Activity Data.
I have not tested it on my real watch yet to see if this also works just while wearing it, and not during an "activity" .

Comment: Correct, although checks for invalid values will be helpful. E.g.

private function getHeartRateAI() {
    var hr = Activity.getActivityInfo().currentHeartRate;
    if (hr != null && hr != 0 && hr != 255) {
      return hr;
    }
    return "--";
  }